# How to solve 'ownCloud Server does not support Microsoft Windows' in xampp?

Tags: windows, windows-10, xampp, owncloud

I am trying to use owncloud. I installed it in xampp. but this message shows:   'OwnCloud Server does not support Microsoft Windows'.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use Linux. https://owncloud.org/download/#owncloud-server

Answer (score 0):

Owncloud doesn't seem to have a Windows server version that is supported. However you do have some options.
You could run it in a docker container. Docker will run Linux in a container and have Owncloud preinstalled.
You can see there are many images provided on the website: https://hub.docker.com/search?q=owncloud&type=image

If you are not familiar with Docker and find it hard to learn you can also try one of the ready made VM images on the download page ( https://owncloud.org/download/ ). For example the Virtualbox one can be downloaded and imported to Virtualbox.